# Alternatives to indexedDB which allows bulk upload and work with large quantities of data

Tags: indexeddb

We are choosing tools for development our next app version which will start soon. One of the examined options - indexedDB for storing database with resources locally in client's browser. Everything was great till we started test high loads. According to our scenarios are possible situation with the bases up to a million objects. So, when we trying to write to the database a millions of simple objects (three fields) begin serious problems.

```
{
  deviceID: '10.20.30.99',
  type: 'cam',
  name: 'simco-cam'
}
```

The browser freezes, and the database dies. After that, it is impossible not to change anything, and not even to remove the db. The database is constantly returns "pending" status. In addition there is no bulk chunks upload option.

Please advise some good alternatives to indexedDB to optimize work with large quantities of data and enable easy bulk upload.

Answer (score 1):

Try throttling your put requests. Instead for `for(obj of objs) store.put(obj)` try using a buffer of 10k objs, and try `setTimeout` between buffer puts.